# Access global class variable in the anonymous function

Tags: ruby, global-variables, anonymous-function, instance-variables

I'm trying to use the `self.instance_exec` method. Instance variable `@legend` in my case gets printed very nicely, but the class variable throws an error:

```
uninitialized class variable @@holiday_legend_counter in Object (NameError)
```

My example code:

```
class Calender
   def initialize(options)
     @@holiday_legend_counter = "a"
     @legend = 'A'
   end

   def print_date(print_date)
     # some calculation to calculate date and the current date  
     self.instance_exec date, @current_start_date, &print_date
   end
end 


print_legend = Proc.new do |date,current_date|
  print @@holiday_legend_counter
  print @legend
end

cal = Calender.new
cal.print_date(print_legend)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you might want can be achieved by slightly modifying the above code like below. Note that when you want to use a class level global variable, it's best to use as an instance variable of the Singleton class. This has the advantage that you don't accidentally override the @@holiday_legend_counter value in a sub class thereby changing the super class's value for @@holiday_legend_counter because @@holiday_legend_counter is shared across the class hierarchy.

```
class Calender

  @holiday_legend_counter = "a"
  class << self;attr_reader :holiday_legend_counter end


  def initialize(options)
    @legend = 'A'
  end

  def print_date(print_date)
    #somecalculation to calculate date and the current date
    self.instance_exec  @current_start_date, &print_date
  end
 end

 print_legend = Proc.new do |date, current_date|
 print Calender.holiday_legend_counter
 print @legend
end

cal = Calender.new("")
cal.print_date(print_legend)
```

Class level instance variables provide better approach when you need to store class level values (not global or instance level)